# If $f\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{x}\cos^{4}tdt$ Then $ f\left(x+\pi\ \right)$ equals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> **Question** $f\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{x}\cos^{4}tdt\ \ Then\ f\left(x+\pi\ \right)$
>   equals

$\left(a\right)f\left(x\right)+f\left(\pi\right)$

$\left(b\right)f\left(x\right)-f\left(\pi\right)$

$\left(c\right)f\left(x\right)f\left(\pi\right)$

$\left(d\right)\frac{f\left(x\right)}{f\left(\pi\right)}$

**My Approach** Let $t = k+\pi \implies dk=dt$

and $k=0\implies t=\pi$

and $k=x \implies k+\pi$

${f\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{x}\cos^{4}tdt}$= ${f\left(x\right)=\int_{\pi}^{k+\pi}\cos^{4}\left(k+\pi\right)dt}$

In this approach if lower limit would have been zero ,then we could
see some chances to solve.

**Edit** I know this may be a wrong approach, but this is all i could
do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

- $$f(x + \pi) = \int_0^{x + \pi} \cos^4(t) \, dt $$
- Split the above interval into the sum of two integral.
- Use the property that $\cos^4(t)$ is a periodic function with period $\pi$.

Comment: I solved it Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the fact 
\begin{align}
\int^{a+b}_0 f(t)\ dt = \int^{a}_0 f(t)\ dt + \int^{a+b}_{a} f(t)\ dt. 
\end{align}
then $u$-sub.

Comment: thanks now i can do this

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=x+\pi$, then $f'(g(x))=\cos^{4}(x+\pi)=\cos^{4}x$. Also, $(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)=\cos^{4}x$, so $(f\circ g)(x)-(f\circ g)(0)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}\cos^{4}tdt=f(x)$, hence $f(x+\pi)-f(\pi)=f(x)$.